# Spring Data JDBC not generating derived Query

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I am using Spring Data JDBC (v1.1.1) automatically pulled in by SpringBoot 2.2.1.RELEASE. For the repository below, the method should automatically derive the Query at start-up time.

```
interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    long countByLastName(String lastName);
...
```

Instead I get this..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No query specified on countByLastName
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryQuery.determineQuery(JdbcRepositoryQuery.java:200) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
```

My entity looks like..

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
```

Any idea why I am getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for query derivation for Spring Data JDBC came with version 2.0.0.

*Note that query derivation currently only supports properties which get stored in the table of the aggregate root for filtering and sorting.*

Comment: I updated the answer since Spring Data JDBC recently added support for query derivation.